Segmentation fault when calling `IpoptApplication::Initialize()`
I am building this with ipopt 3.11.9-2.2build2 on Ubuntu 20.04.6, with GCC 9.4.0:
#include <IpIpoptApplication.hpp>
#include <IpTNLP.hpp>

using namespace Ipopt;

/**
 * @brief Trivial quadratic problem for testing.
 */
class Dummy_NLP : public TNLP
{
public:
    Dummy_NLP()
    {
    }

    virtual ~Dummy_NLP() = default;

    bool get_nlp_info(Index &number_of_variables, Index &number_of_constraints,
        Index &number_of_nonzero_jacobian_entries, Index &number_of_nonzero_hessian_entries,
        IndexStyleEnum &index_style) override
    {
        number_of_variables = 1;
        number_of_constraints = 1;
        number_of_nonzero_jacobian_entries = 1;
        number_of_nonzero_hessian_entries = 1;
        index_style = TNLP::C_STYLE;
        return true;
    }

    bool get_bounds_info(Index n, Number *x_l, Number *x_u, Index m, Number *g_l, Number *g_u) override
    {
        g_l[0] = -2;
        g_u[0] = -2;
        return true;
    }

    bool get_starting_point(Index n, bool init_x, Number *x, bool init_z, Number *z_L, Number *z_U, Index m,
        bool init_lambda, Number *lambda) override
    {
        for (Index i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            x[i] = 0;
        }
        return true;
    }

    bool eval_f(Index n, const Number *x, bool new_x, Number &obj_value) override
    {
        obj_value = std::abs(x[0] * x[0] - 5);
        return true;
    }

    bool eval_grad_f(Index n, const Number *x, bool new_x, Number *grad_f) override
    {
        grad_f[0] = 2 * x[0];
        return true;
    }

    bool eval_g(Index n, const Number *x, bool new_x, Index m, Number *g) override
    {
        g[0] = x[0] * x[0];
        return true;
    }

    bool eval_jac_g(Index n, const Number *x, bool new_x, Index m, Index nele_jac, Index *iRow, Index *jCol,
        Number *values) override
    {
        if (values == nullptr) {
            iRow[0] = 0;
            jCol[0] = 0;
        } else {
            values[0] = 2 * x[0];
        }
        return true;
    }

    void finalize_solution(SolverReturn status, Index n, const Number *x, const Number *z_L, const Number *z_U, Index m,
        const Number *g, const Number *lambda, Number obj_value, const IpoptData *ip_data,
        IpoptCalculatedQuantities *ip_cq) override
    {
    }
};

int main(int argv, char **argc)
{
    SmartPtr<TNLP> mynlp = new Dummy_NLP();
    SmartPtr<IpoptApplication> app = IpoptApplicationFactory();
    app->Options()->SetNumericValue("tol", 3.82e-6);
    app->Options()->SetStringValue("mu_strategy", "adaptive");
    app->Options()->SetStringValue("output_file", "ipopt.out");
    ApplicationReturnStatus status;
    status = app->Initialize();
    if (status != Solve_Succeeded) {
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << "*** Error during initialization!" << std::endl;
        return (int)status;
    }
    status = app->OptimizeTNLP(mynlp);
    return (int)status;
}

It crashes in Ipopt/src/Interfaces/IpIpoptApplication.cpp, in the Ipopt::IpoptApplication::OptimizeTNLP function, called by app->Initialize(). I don't have any other information, this is all the debugger can show me.
Is there something wrong with the code or the problem parameters, or does this look like a setup problem?

Building from source with MUMPS (the version recommended in ipopt's README) fixed it. I don't know why Ubuntu's package didn't work.
